# Python: Extract numbers from a string like date,fraction, percentage and so on

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I would like to indentify all types of numbers in a string.
Example:

```
a = 'I 0.34 -345 3/4 3% want to  get -0.34 2018-09 all numbers'
```

Result:

```
['I', '_num', '_num', '_num', '_num', 'want', 'to', 'get', '_num', '_num', 'all', 'numbers']
```

it is a nlp project and I wonder if there is a better method to get the result.
I could just list all the types then use regex but it's not concise,someone has good ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list comprehension here *is* pretty concise:

```
a = 'I 0.34 -345 3/4 3% want to  get -0.34 2018-09 all numbers'
pattern = re.compile('\d')
result = ['_num' if re.search(pattern, word) else word for word in re.compile(' +').split(a)]
```

If the double space in your input (`want to  get`) was a typo, then you can split on a space alone rather than having to use a regex:

```
pattern = re.compile('\d')
result = ['_num' if re.search(pattern, word) else word for word in a.split(' ')]
```

Result:

```
['I', '_num', '_num', '_num', '_num', 'want', 'to', 'get', '_num', '_num', 'all', 'numbers']
```

Comment: Thank you for your help,by the way,if I want to mark the punctuation at the same time,what can I do?Thank you again and your idea is great^_^